# How to install MySQL server on client system with my software setup, in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, wpf, winforms

I have create a Windows application in WPF using Visual Studio 2013, and I'm using MySQL as database, now I want to include MySQL as a distributable package in my setup file.

I am new to development and have very little idea about deploying the software, and i have been searching  over the internet but hardly finds any good article which explains the steps to perform the task.

Comment: MySQL is a client/server database. Use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) or [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my client wants the database to be in MySQL only of the desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

A MySQL database is supposed to be setup on a (remote) database server that the client applications connect to. You don't (or at least you shouldn't) set up a server on each workstation where your client application is installed on.

What you probably want is a self-contained database that can be shipped with your application and run "as-is" without any remote servers or specific setup.

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) is a popular example of such a database.

**Getting started with SQLite in C#:** http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my client wants the database to be in MySQL only of the desktop application.

Comment: Then you need to install MySQL on all client machines.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects

And then follow this:

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/04/24/visual-studio-2013-installer-projects-ndash-hello-world-installer.aspx

There will be settings which you will be setting when creating installer with the wizard, one will be like pre-requisites for the program and will ask you for a MSI location for that program. Dump the location of your LocalDB or whatever MySQL software that you are using (Popular ones are SQLite/SQL Server Express). When the user starts to install the program it will make them install your SQL prerequisite software before moving onto installing your program.

Comment: Thanks for the Help, i have installed the above template, but i am not able to include the My-SQL community Server msi in the project, its giving me an error as "Not a valid file type for a custom action.", please suggest what to do..

Comment: I used LocalDB.msi and it worked fine. Why dont you use LocalDB its much easier.